# nodejs dgram udp socket listen on specific interface

Tags: node.js, udp, bind

I'm currently implementing a legacy proprietary udp protocol with nodejs. It's necessary to know from which network interface the packages were coming from.

I tried to bind two sockets to their network addresses. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

```
> ifconfig
en0: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 3c:22:fb:4b:fc:31 
    inet6 fe80::1c0f:d365:a86d:be5d%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x6 
    inet 192.168.178.70 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.178.255
    inet6 2001:16b8:2ef3:4200:10d4:27f8:4945:c138 prefixlen 64 autoconf secured 
    inet6 2001:16b8:2ef3:4200:d919:b3b1:6220:ca12 prefixlen 64 autoconf temporary 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en8: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=6407<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    ether 9c:eb:e8:85:92:6c 
    inet6 fe80::10b6:fa35:b1ee:ca68%en8 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x1d 
    inet 192.168.2.10 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
    status: active
```

```js
import * as dgram from 'dgram';

const socket1 = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
const socket2 = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
socket1.on('error', (error)=>{
  console.log('socket1 error:', JSON.stringify(error, null, 4));
})
socket2.on('error', (error)=>{
  console.log('socket2 error:', JSON.stringify(error, null, 4));
})
socket1.on('message', (message)=>{
  console.log('socket1 message:', JSON.stringify(message, null, 4));
})
socket2.on('message', (message)=>{
  console.log('socket2 message:', JSON.stringify(message, null, 4));
})
socket1.bind({
  port:2000,
  address: '192.168.2.0',
  exclusive:false,
}, ()=>{
  socket1.setBoradcast(true)
});
socket2.bind({
  port:2000,
  address: '192.168.178.0',
  exclusive:false,
}, ()=>{
  socket2.setBoradcast(true)
});
```

Produces the following output:

```
socket1 error: {
    "errno": "EADDRNOTAVAIL",
    "code": "EADDRNOTAVAIL",
    "syscall": "bind",
    "address": "192.168.2.0",
    "port": 2000
}
socket2 error: {
    "errno": "EADDRNOTAVAIL",
    "code": "EADDRNOTAVAIL",
    "syscall": "bind",
    "address": "192.168.178.0",
    "port": 2000
}
```

Edit 1:

Thanks to answer of @Steffen Ullrich I'm now able to bind the sockets.

But now I cannot receive broadcast messages on these sockets on macos (It works on windows). Any chance to receive those broadcasts also on macos?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong addresses:

```
inet 192.168.178.70 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.178.255
                ^^^^
inet 192.168.2.10 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.255
              ^^^^
```

vs.

```
address: '192.168.2.0',
                   ^^^
address: '192.168.178.0',
                     ^^^
```

Comment: Thank you! This is totally correct. But now I can't receive broadcasts on this sockets on macos. On windows it works now as expected